# Best mysql config for my server

Tags: mysql, configuration, mysql-5.7

I have dedicated server, my CPU usage is too high (80%-100%) and memory only use 9GB.

**RAM 32 gb and CPU Dual Xeon E5-2670(8core and 16 thread)**

I have 25000 users that use my android application

My database table only `innodb`. What is best config?

sorry for bad English

**mysql5.7**

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com or here.
Any SSD or all rotating media?
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis.

Answer (score 1):

High CPU almost always means inefficient queries.  The fix may be as simple as a better index (possibly composite), or rephrasing a `SELECT`.  Find out what queries are most commonly running and let's discuss them.

About the only tunable that *might* be incorrect is `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, which needs to be about 70% of *available* RAM.

You might be able to catch slow queries by using `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` repeatedly.  But the slowlog is better.  See [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog).

Comment: i second the inefficient queries, slow log enabled the parse with pt-query-digest for human readable results

Answer (score 0):

Please use MySQL Tuner in long running production server.

- MySQL Tuner connects to a running MySQL instance and offer configuration suggestions to optimize the database for your workload.
- The longer the server has been running, the better the advice mysqltuner can provide. In a production environment, consider waiting for at least 24 hours before running the tool.
- You can install mysqltuner from the Ubuntu or Fedora/RedHat repositories:

   Ubuntu: 
  `sudo apt-get install mysqltuner`

   Fedora: 
  `sudo dnf install mysqltuner`

   RedHat: 
  `sudo yum install mysqltuner`
- Then once its been installed, run: `mysqltuner` and wait for its final report. The top section provides  general information about the database server, and the  bottom section provides tuning suggestions to alter in  your my.cnf. Most of these can be altered live on the   server without restarting.